# A polyhedron whose faces are pairwise adjacent

Tags: geometry, 3d, polyhedra

I've heard there exists a polyhedron (besides tetrahedron) whose faces are pairwise adjacent but I can't find any information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be referring to the (nonconvex) Szilassi polyhedron, described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szilassi_polyhedron – it has seven hexagonal faces, each adjacent to all of the others.